Snowflake query using in percentile_disc
I am trying to solve this question where I wanted a second opinion to check on the query I have build so far.
I have used a percentile_disc function and as been new to sql queries wanted to know if my query makes sense for the question mentioned below.
Question : Write an SQL query to analyse the distribution of TotalCharges by PrincipalDiagnosis and Sex. Use percentiles to describe the distribution
Any help will be appreciated.
Query I have written so far using CTE in snowflakes
with CTE as
(
select
  sex,
  PrincipalDiagnosis,
  sum (different charges) as totalcharges,
  percentile_disc (0.50) within group (order by totalcharges asc) over (partition by  sex, PrincipalDiagnosis,) as median
  from datset
  group by 1,2
)
select
   sex,
  PrincipalDiagnosis,
  totalcharges
  from cte
 order by  sex, PrincipalDiagnosis

enter image description here

Hi - please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text appropriately formatted. So what’s your actual question? What’s the issue with the SQL you’ve written?

I would assume you want to use RATIO_TO_REPORT to find the percentages for each partition, so comparisions can be made (like bar chart or pie chart) as compared to PERCENTILE_DISC fetches the value at fixed percentages, which is better for getting histogram like reports of continuous values spaces.

Hi @SimeonPilgrim, I am a bit confused particularly about the mention that "use percentile to describe the distribution" that's why though of using percentile_disc or percentile_cont. Can you please help in tuning the query using Ratio_to_report?
